# UI-Sortable with Angular filter for ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui

It seems that the UI-sortable (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable) plug in does not play well if there is a filter in the list that is being ng-repeated by angular. The drag and drops do not work as intended.

This is shown by these two fiddles:

First: Has filter - the drag and drop will not stay in place.

http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/2886/

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="Controller">
  <ul ui-sortable="sortableOptions" id="test" ng-model="items">
    <li class="line" ng-repeat="item in items | filter: myFilter">        
        {{item.name}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ui.sortable']);

myApp.controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';
    $scope.items = [
        {name: 'TEST'},
        {name: 'TEST2'}, 
        {name: 'TEST3'}, 
        {name: 'TEST4'},
        {name: 'TEST5'},
        {name: 'TEST6'},
        {name: 'TEST7'},
        {name: 'TEST8'}
    ]

    $scope.myFilter = function (item) { 
        return item.name !== 'TEST';
    };
    $scope.sortableOptions = {
        opacity: '0.8',
        axis: 'y',
        tolerance: 'pointer',
    }
}]);
```

Second: Has no filter - works as intended.

JS SAME,

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="Controller">
  <ul ui-sortable="sortableOptions" id="test" ng-model="items">
    <li class="line" ng-repeat="item in items">
      {{item.name}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/2887/

I will create an issue on their github repo as well, but if anyone has a work around that would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable/blob/master/README.md) you can see

> Filters that manipulate the model (like filter, orderBy, limitTo,...) should be applied in the controller instead of the ng-repeat ([refer to the provided examples](http://codepen.io/thgreasi/pen/mzGbq)).
>   This is the preferred way since it:
>    - is performance wise better
>    - reduces the chance of code duplication
>    - is suggested by the angularJS team
>    - it does not break the matching of the generated DOM elements and the ng-model's items

So yeah, don't do filtering in the view, it is not intended to work with ui-sortable.

For example:

JS:

```
 $scope.filtered= $filter('filter')($scope.items, $scope.myFilter);
```

HTML:

```
<li class="line" ng-repeat="item in filtered">        
    {{item.name}}
</li>
```

Comment: But: Don't forget that this solution will delete the items in your array. You can use one scope array and one javascript array. The original data are in your javascript array.

Answer (score 0):

you are passing an array in ng-model.

**ngModel** directory works like just another attribute like id which is accessible by angular.

and **ngModel** is mostly used in the tags which produces data, like **input**, **textarea**, **select** and other custom directives.

simply instead of accessing the data from id by using the general DOM identification like

$scope.variable = document.getElementById('someElement').value

angular uses ngModel directive to bind the data in both ways.